# React Native Android - Error while trying to write custom UI component for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom viewpager that i'm trying to write a custom UI module for in android. I wanted to learn how to do this as i can only port my application to react if its possible to easily write these ManagerClass on the android side for all my custom modules.

```
    protected MaterialViewPager createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
    mViewPager = new MaterialViewPager(themedReactContext);


    mViewPager.setMaterialViewPagerListener(new MaterialViewPager.Listener() {
        @Override
        public HeaderDesign getHeaderDesign(int page) {
            switch (page) {
                case 0:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.green,
                            "https://fs01.androidpit.info/a/63/0e/android-l-wallpapers-630ea6-h900.jpg");
                case 1:
                    return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.blue,
                            "http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2014/06/wallpaper_51.jpg");

            return null;
        }
    });
    mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount());
    mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(mViewPager.getViewPager());

    return mViewPager;
}
```

I have in the MainActivity.java

```
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(
        ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
            new MaterialViewPagerManager()
    );
    }
```

then on react side, i created the js for the module

```
// MatViewPager.js

var { requireNativeComponent } = require('react-native');

var viewpager = {
  name: 'MatViewPager',
};

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTMatViewPager', viewpager);
```

and finally in index.android.js

```
var {
 Text,
 View,
 MatViewPager,
} = React;

[...]

render: function() {
 return (
  <MatViewPager>
  </MatViewPager>
 );
 }
```

the error i am getting is

```
Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) 
but got: undefined.
```

any react devs can point me on the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you `ManagerClass` `getName` method returns `"RCTMatViewPager"`.

Secondly you need to import your js module. It's not in React module, as you created your own MatViewPager.js:

```
var MatViewPager = require('./{path_to_your_modules}/MatViewPager');
```